# large data download and local processing and storage for monotouch app

Tags: json, sqlite, xamarin.ios, local-storage, xamarin

This is a more general software architecture question for monotouch / xamarin enviorment.

Here's my problem:

The app I am currently building downloads around 30k of json objects (6mb) on app launch. Data is then locally stored, so all screens make local db (sqlite) calls.

Main issue is the time it takes to perform the download. At the moment, it's about 36s total on the simulator, split between following tasks:

1. download ~ 10 sec
2. data conversion (json to native obj) ~ 16 sec
3. db insert ~ 10 sec

This is far too long, especially when I compare it with similar apps that are on the appstore. I feel like I am not doing something right here, or not being aware of an alternative way? Here are the improvements I've implemented:

1. gzip response - currently 6mb, with gzip it goes down to ~ 1mb
2. installed ServiceStack.Text json serialiser, about 2.5x faster than json.net (but still 16 seconds is too long)
3. flattened json response, so I can execute db.InsertAll() on response array (without extra looping etc) for more robost db import (transactions)
4. one call per day limitation

Now, what I want to do is to display local data on app launch and initialise download / updater in the background. The only problem is the time it takes to download + newly installed apps won't have any local data to display...

My questions are:

1. is mvc 4 api -> json convert -> sqlite import a good approach for this type of app? If not - what are the alternatives?

I've been thinking of server returning actual sqlite file instead, in a zipped response, or returning zipped db commands... Or perhaps sqlite is not suitable for this type of app? Are there any better alternatives for local storage? .net serializer / xml etc?

Thanks for all your suggestions!

Comment: Hi, i have the very similar situation. Can you give me a example of how to use gzip response?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to do your work asynchronously - and you're lucky since C# makes that very easy. E.g.

1. Start a background download;
2. Process (background) the object as they are downloaded;
3. Insert (background) objects as they are processed;
4. If applicable update the UI (from the main thread) for every X object you add;

Since the download is (mostly, see note) network bound then your CPU will be idle for many seconds. That's a waste of time considering your next step (processing) will be CPU bound. Even more since the step afterward will likely be I/O bound (database).

IOW it *looks like* a good idea to run all three tasks simultaneously while giving feedback of the progress (showing data or a progress bar) to the application user.

Note #1: A **gzipped** response will download faster. OTOH it will take some extra (CPU) time to uncompress locally. It should be faster but it's worth measuring both options (e.g. using Apple's Instrument tool, which works nicely with Xamarin.iOS).

Note #2: A **zip** file, as a response, will also need extra time (to uncompress). That's not something you want to do sequentially after the download (but you could uncompress it as it's downloaded).